# image watermark not work in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

give text as a watermark on picture in codeigniter code can not run properly.

```
public function new()
    {
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $config['sourse_image'] ='./SaveImage/fer.jpg';
        $config['wm_text'] = 'SaleScrap';
        $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
        $config['wm_font_path'] = 'system/fonts/texb.ttf';
        $config['wm_font_size'] = '16';
        $config['wm_font_color'] = 'ffffff';
        $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
        $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
        $config['wm_padding'] = '20';
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        if($this->image_lib->watermark())
        {
            echo "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
```

code not work and can not give output when code run **Log File** give this Error

```
ERROR - 2018-08-29 11:49:54 --> You must specify a source image in your preferences.
ERROR - 2018-08-29 11:49:54 --> Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION 1

```
$config['sourse_image'] ='./SaveImage/fer.jpg';
```

correct spelling of source_image

SOLUTION 2.

You should try this structure:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
// Set your config up
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
// Do your manipulation
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

If nothing works, the error might actually be the whole issue.
Check if you have gd installed, on linux you would do

```
sudo yum list installed | grep php
```

If not installed, install it

```
sudo yum install php-gd-package-name
```

RESTART your apache

sudo service httpd restart